# Python ODBC Connect to SQL Server with Service Account (trusted_connection=no)

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, authentication, odbc

I connect to my server no problem with SQL Alchemy or Pyodbc so long as I use a trusted connection:

```
pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServer;Port=1433;Database=myDB;trusted_connection=yes")

sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://myServer/myDB?trusted_connection=yes&driver=SQL+Server')
```

But I need to connect with a service account with basic Windows Authentication. When I try to add the UID/PWD like so:

```
sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://myUserName:myPassWord@myServer?driver=SQL+Server?trusted_connection=no")

pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myServre;DATABASE=myDB;UID=myUserName;PWD=myPassword')
```

I get the error "Login failed for user 'myUserName'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] "

Bonus try:

```
sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://myUserName:myPassword@myDB?driver=SQL+Server?trusted_connection=no")
```

Returns '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long (0) (SQLDriverConnect)'

Using SQL Server 2018.

I've verified that the service account has all the right permissions on the DB I'm trying to connect to. FWIW, I've also tried connecting using my own Windows credentials instead of the service account's (but with trusted_connection=no) and I get the same error messages.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> get the error "Login failed for user 'myUserName'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] "

None of the Microsoft ODBC drivers support using Windows Integrated Authentication (NTLM or Kerberos) using provided credentials.  This connection string

```
DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myServre;DATABASE=myDB;UID=myUserName;PWD=myPassword
```

is for SQL Auth, where you have a login and a database user created in SQL Server.

eg:

```
use mydb
create login myUserName with password='myPassword'
create user myUserName for login myUserName
grant select to myUserName
```

To use Windows Auth with this driver you have to run your program as the target user, do Windows-level impersonation, store a credential in the Windows Credential store, or use `runas /netonly`.

Comment: That explains my problem connecting... Thanks! The question is then, how do I run this python script via the Windows Task Scheduler using the service account? I'm running with the highest permissions, but as far as I've been able to see I can't use runas /netonly.

Comment: You can configure the task to run as any user you want.  It's in the Security Options under the General tab.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. For future reference, this is what I had to do to get the service account working:

Open "Local Security Policy" and add it to "Local Policy > User Rights Assignments" Log on as a service AND Log on as a batch job.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/4692e927-6962-4327-b393-964a57fa38fe/automating-with-task-scheduler-using-service-account-active-directory-windows-login-to-connect-to?forum=ITCG